# How can I set up Knockoutjs for Glimpse?

Tags: knockout.js, glimpse

I'm trying to set up the [nockoutJS inspector for Glimpse
0.1.5](http://www.nuget.org/packages/glimpse-knockout) on a simple SPA which includes several KnockoutJS view models. So far I have installed the KnockoutJS inspector plus Glimpse via Nuget and switched Glimpse on via /glimpse.axd. I have also verified that /Scripts/glimpse-knockout.js is loaded and the first  pubsub.subscribe(...) function in that script file is called when I start my app.

However, when I view the Glimpse KnockoutJS tab, the tab stays completely blank, even after using my app so that several models are bound.

Is there anything that I have missed when installing? I'd gladly RTFM, but there doesn't seem to be any.

Comment: do you see any Javascript errors in the console when using the application?

Comment: I don't see any now, but I did have some problems with model binding when I wrote this question (hence my attempt to install the Glimpse extension in order to analyze them). I assumed that the extension would still work, just as a debugger can analyze broken code. Most probably this was not the case though. I just tried it again and now it worked. Thanks for the hint! :)

Answer (score 0):

As cgijbels suggested in his comment above, the problem was probably related with a bug in my view model since the extension is working fine now. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the situation as is was before, since I have no version control commit from when I wrote the question.